# VLAN configuration for 2 gateways

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I have a Cisco SG200-50 50 port switch and I want to configure it so there is one big LAN (all computers on the switch can see each other), but half the computers only see the first gateway, and half the computers only see the other gateway (ie computers plugged into the left side get gateway 1, computers plugged into the right side get gateway 2).

Here's the current configuration (for 3 gateways), after fooling around with no idea what I'm doing.

```
interface vlan 1
 no ip address dhcp 
!
interface vlan 2
 name Backplane 
!
interface vlan 10
 name Servers 
!
interface vlan 101
 name "Modem/Router A" 
!
interface vlan 102
 name "Modem/Router B" 
!
interface vlan 103
 name "Modem/Router C" 
!
interface vlan 201
 name "Network A" 
!
interface vlan 202
 name "Network B" 
!
interface vlan 203
 name "Network C" 
!
interface vlan 1000
 name backplatest 
!
interface vlan 1001
 name routera 
!
interface vlan 1002
 name routerb 
!
interface gigabitethernet1
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 101 
!
interface gigabitethernet2
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 102 
!
interface gigabitethernet3
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 103 
!
interface gigabitethernet4
 switchport mode general 
!
interface gigabitethernet5
 switchport mode general 
!
interface gigabitethernet6
 switchport mode general 
!
interface gigabitethernet7
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 201 
!
interface gigabitethernet8
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 201 
!
interface gigabitethernet9
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 201 
!
interface gigabitethernet10
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 201 
!
interface gigabitethernet11
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 201 
!
interface gigabitethernet12
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,101,201 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 201 
!
interface gigabitethernet13
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 202 
!
interface gigabitethernet14
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 202 
!
interface gigabitethernet15
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 202 
!
interface gigabitethernet16
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 202 
!
interface gigabitethernet17
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 202 
!
interface gigabitethernet18
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,102,202 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 202 
!
interface gigabitethernet19
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 203 
!
interface gigabitethernet20
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 203 
!
interface gigabitethernet21
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 203 
!
interface gigabitethernet22
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 203 
!
interface gigabitethernet23
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 203 
!
interface gigabitethernet24
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 2,10,103,203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 203 
!
interface gigabitethernet25
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,201-203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet26
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,201-203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet27
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,201-203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet28
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,201-203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet29
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,201-203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet30
 switchport mode general 
 switchport general allowed vlan add 10,201-203 untagged 
 switchport general pvid 10 
!
interface gigabitethernet31
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 1000 
!
interface gigabitethernet32
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 1000 
!
interface gigabitethernet33
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 1000 
!
interface gigabitethernet34
 switchport mode access 
 switchport access vlan 1000 
 switchport general pvid 1000 
!
```

Comment: Do you have access to the switch?  If so, log in and get the running config and paste it in your original question.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why that's necessary, but I've pasted it anyways.

Comment: Better yet, log in to the switch and grab the output of this command:  **show vlan brief**

Comment: This switch doesn't support telnet afaik. There's only a web based GUI.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:** I think I understand what you are asking, hopefully this answer will be a little more useful.

Essentially what you need to do is make the VLAN's from the first half of the switch accessible to the second half of the switch.

There should be a way to add in this VLAN to the ports that you want to have access to both.  Since you just want to use one network, we will configure "**Network A**"  for access to the entire switch.

From a command line (can you SSH to the switch?) it looks like this:

```
conf t
int gigabitethernet1-gigabitethernet24
switchport access vlan 101
switchport access vlan 201
exit
```

This will assign the first half of the switch to Network A (vlan 201) and tell it to use Router A (vlan 101).  You would do something similar for the second half of the switch.

```
int gigabitethernet25-gigabitethernet50
switchport access vlan 102
switchport access vlan 201
exit
```

This will assign the second half of the switch to Network A (vlan 201) and will tell it to use Router B (vlan 102).

This should meet the requirement or at least get you going in the right direction but I highly advise that you **be sure to test this config before you write any changes to the switch!**

This same set of steps can be accomplished through a web GUI, so the idea would still be the same butthe process would just be slightly different.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Lets just assume I have a brand new Cisco SG200-50.

I have two separate internet gateways, but I want 1 LAN. I want a way to configure the VLAN's so that everyone connected to the left side of the switch can only see the left gateway, and the people connected to the right side of the switch can only see the right gateway.

I also want everyone to be able to see each other (but only see their respective gateways).

Comment: And what ports on the switch are on what side?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, but for the sake of argument, lets say ports 1-24 are on the left side and 25-50 are on the right. Port 1 is plugged into the left gateway and port 25 is plugged into the right one.

Comment: It does matter if you want to configure the switch the way you want :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with what "I think" you are wanting.

Comment: What type should I configure the ports for? Trunk/Access/General?

Comment: Also, do I leave them as tagged or untagged?

Comment: Last question, what should the PVID's be. I tried [this](http://i50.tinypic.com/24fww3r.png), but it's not working. Port 33 and 34 can see each other, but can't see the routers plugged into 31 and 32.